# Images sometimes don't appear till resizing window in Safari (CSS3)

Tags: css, safari

i reduced a "zurb foundation" problem to the following minimum of code. When i open a website with that code in Safari, sometimes not all images load. Sometimes none, sometimes just one or two. In the moment i resize the browser window, all lost images appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        p { float: left; }

        img { box-sizing: border-box;
              max-width: 100%;
              border: solid;
              }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p><img src='1.jpg'></p>
    <p><img src='2.jpg'></p>
    <p><img src='3.jpg'></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe it's just a rendering/speed problem of Safari and the combination of `box-Sizing`, `float`, `border` and `max-width`. When i try it locally in my file system, there seems to be no problem (fast). On two different web servers, images appear different certain.

'Normal' server:
http://test5.topiclodge.com

Slow server:
http://wiki.norm-konform.de/test/

I testet it on 3 Macs (Safari versions 6.0.3 and 6.0.5)

Maybe there is a workaround or any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was getting this too, when I had an image with an onload attribute which called some jquery to resize the image. It loaded and was visible for a nanosecond, then went blank. Resizing the Safari window manually then made it appear again. I switched to a CSS approach.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit browsers don't like images without width and height attributes added to them. Add width and height to the images and try again.